# Questionnaire based WooCommerce product filter

Tags: woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to make a questionnaire based WooCommerce product filter with the help of gravity form.

What I exactly want - http://www.clinique.com/diagnostics

Hint - https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-questionnaire-based-woocommerce-product-filter/

can anyone help me with the coding part ( loop through the answers provided by a shopper and save them in an array and query WooCommerce products which include the attributes selected and list them)?

Comment: so what did you do ?